# Compare the two tables and update the value in a Flag column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables and the values like this

```
`create table InputLocationTable(SKUID int,InputLocations varchar(100),Flag varchar(100))
create table Location(SKUID int,Locations varchar(100))

insert into InputLocationTable(SKUID,InputLocations) values(11,'Loc1, Loc2, Loc3, Loc4, Loc5, Loc6')
insert into InputLocationTable(SKUID,InputLocations) values(12,'Loc1, Loc2')
insert into InputLocationTable(SKUID,InputLocations) values(13,'Loc4,Loc5')

insert into Location(SKUID,Locations) values(11,'Loc3')
insert into Location(SKUID,Locations) values(11,'Loc4')
insert into Location(SKUID,Locations) values(11,'Loc5')
insert into Location(SKUID,Locations) values(11,'Loc7')
insert into Location(SKUID,Locations) values(12,'Loc10')
insert into Location(SKUID,Locations) values(12,'Loc1')
insert into Location(SKUID,Locations) values(12,'Loc5')
insert into Location(SKUID,Locations) values(13,'Loc4')
insert into Location(SKUID,Locations) values(13,'Loc2')
insert into Location(SKUID,Locations) values(13,'Loc2')`
```

I need to get the output by matching SKUID's from Each tables and Update the value in Flag column as shown in the screenshot, I have tried something like this code

```
`SELECT  STUFF((select ','+ Data.C1 
FROM   
(select 
  n.r.value('.', 'varchar(50)') AS C1
from InputLocation as T
   cross apply (select cast('<r>'+replace(replace(Location,'&','&'), ',', '</r><r>')+'</r>' as xml)) as S(XMLCol)
  cross apply S.XMLCol.nodes('r') as n(r))  DATA
WHERE  data.C1 NOT IN (SELECT Location
                FROM   Location) for  xml path('')),1,1,'') As Output`
```

But not convinced with output and also i am trying to avoid xml path code, because performance is not first place for this code, I need the output like the below screenshot. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: you mean to say that Update The Flag Column WHERE INputLocation not IN Location Table location scolumn

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly...you said, that you managed to find a solution with for xml path but would rather avoid using that. Well, "FOR XML PATH" afaik is the best and recommended solution to do string concatenation until SQL Server 2016. In 2016 MSFT added the STRING_AGG function. On SQL Server 2008 you could use a custom assembly as an alternative. But that has its downsides. Take a look at https://www.sqlshack.com/string-concatenation-done-right-part-2-an-effective-technique/.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replay, I just avoided using xml path, that doesn't mean i should not use and all, I am using SQL server 2014, So please suggest me better code or answer for that

Comment: Ya you are right  Alfaiz Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to first look at why you think the `XML` approach is not performing well enough for your needs, as [it has actually been shown to perform very well for larger input strings](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings).

If you only need to handle input strings of up to either 4000 or 8000 characters (non `max` `nvarchar` and `varchar` types respectively), you can utilise a tally table contained within an inline table valued function [which will also perform very well](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).  The version I use can be found at the end of this post.

Utilising this function we can split out the values in your `InputLocations` column, though we still need to use `for xml` to concatenate them back together for your desired format:

```
-- Define data
declare @InputLocationTable table (SKUID int,InputLocations varchar(100),Flag varchar(100));
declare @Location table (SKUID int,Locations varchar(100));

insert into @InputLocationTable(SKUID,InputLocations) values (11,'Loc1, Loc2, Loc3, Loc4, Loc5, Loc6'),(12,'Loc1, Loc2'),(13,'Loc4,Loc5'),(14,'Loc1');
insert into @Location(SKUID,Locations) values (11,'Loc3'),(11,'Loc4'),(11,'Loc5'),(11,'Loc7'),(12,'Loc10'),(12,'Loc1'),(12,'Loc5'),(13,'Loc4'),(13,'Loc2'),(13,'Loc2'),(14,'Loc1');

--Query

-- Derived table splits out the values held within the InputLocations column
with i as
(
    select i.SKUID
          ,i.InputLocations
          ,s.item as Loc
    from @InputLocationTable as i
        cross apply dbo.fn_StringSplit4k(replace(i.InputLocations,' ',''),',',null) as s
)
select il.SKUID
      ,il.InputLocations
      ,isnull('Add '    -- The split Locations are then matched to those already in @Location and those not present are concatenated together.
              + stuff((select ', ' + i.Loc
                      from i
                          left join @Location as l
                              on i.SKUID = l.SKUID
                                  and i.Loc = l.Locations
                      where il.SKUID = i.SKUID
                          and l.SKUID is null
                      for xml path('')
                      )
                     ,1,2,''
                     )
              ,'No Flag') as Flag
from @InputLocationTable as il
order by il.SKUID;
```

Output:

```
+-------+------------------------------------+----------------------+
| SKUID |           InputLocations           |         Flag         |
+-------+------------------------------------+----------------------+
|    11 | Loc1, Loc2, Loc3, Loc4, Loc5, Loc6 | Add Loc1, Loc2, Loc6 |
|    12 | Loc1, Loc2                         | Add Loc2             |
|    13 | Loc4,Loc5                          | Add Loc5             |
|    14 | Loc1                               | No Flag              |
+-------+------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

For `nvarchar` input (I have different functions for `varchar` and `max` type input) this is my version of the string splitting function linked above:

```
create function [dbo].[fn_StringSplit4k]
(
  @str nvarchar(4000) = ' '        -- String to split.
 ,@delimiter as nvarchar(1) = ','  -- Delimiting value to split on.
 ,@num as int = null               -- Which value in the list to return.  NULL returns all.
)
returns table
as
return
     -- Start tally table with 10 rows.
 with n(n)   as (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1)

     -- Select the same number of rows as characters in @str as incremental row numbers.
     -- Cross joins increase exponentially to a max possible 10,000 rows to cover largest @str length.
  ,t(t)   as (select top (select len(isnull(@str,'')) a) row_number() over (order by (select null)) from n n1,n n2,n n3,n n4)

     -- Return the position of every value that follows the specified delimiter.
  ,s(s)   as (select 1 union all select t+1 from t where substring(isnull(@str,''),t,1) = @delimiter)

     -- Return the start and length of every value, to use in the SUBSTRING function.
     -- ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the last value where there is no delimiter at the end of the string.
  ,l(s,l) as (select s,isnull(nullif(charindex(@delimiter,isnull(@str,''),s),0)-s,4000) from s)

 select rn
       ,item
 from(select row_number() over(order by s) as rn
            ,substring(@str,s,l) as item
      from l
     ) a
 where rn = @num
   or @num is null;
go
```